# Hibernate/JPA - Variable field name is @NamedQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Is it possible to do the following:

```
@NamedQuery(name=Report.RECORD_BY_TYPE_AND_FIELD_VALUE,query="SELECT r FROM Report r WHERE r.:field <=:value")
```

I need to be able to query based on a dynamic column name.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to do the above, however Eclipse produces the following type of method in its auto generated DAO's

```
public List<Table> findByProperty(String propertyName, final Object value) {
    EntityManagerHelper.log("finding TableName instance with property: "
            + propertyName + ", value: " + value, Level.INFO, null);
    try {
        final String queryString = "select model from TableName model where model."
                + propertyName + "= :propertyValue";
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("propertyValue", value);
        return query.getResultList();
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("find by property name failed",
                Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```